# Why repeat function didn't work?

Tags: python-3.x, repeat, python-itertools

I'm new to Python.
Can anyone explain why the `repeat` function doesn't do anything here?

```
from itertools import repeat

def f():
    print([5,8,9])

repeat(f(),3)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`repeat` is a *generator function*.  When you call it, the function does **not** start executing. Instead, a generator object is initialized and returned.

To obtain the items, you need to iterate over the generator object:

```
for x in repeat(f(), 3):
    print(x)
```

Or:

```
items = list(repeat(f(), 3))
```

Comment: I tried below codes it gives output as
None
None
None
and
[None, None, None]

def f1():
    print([5,8,9])

for x in repeat(f1(), 3):
    print(x)
 

def f2():
    print([5,8,9])
    
items = list(repeat(f2(), 3))
print(items)

but I want to print
[5,8,9]
[5,8,9]
[5,8,9] insted

Comment: @NaduniWarnakulasooriya you should `return [5,8,9]` instead of `print([5,8,9])` in `f`.